# Grammatical function of time periods

Tags: nouns

What's the grammatical function of "1600's" in the following sentence?

> It was a cutting edge technology of the 1600's.

To me it looks like a noun, meaning 17th century, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Its grammatical function is **head** of the NP "the 1600s", which is **complement** of the preposition "of".

Comment: I suspect what you want to know may be something different than the usual meaning of "grammatical function" (which is basically what BillJ's comment answers), but you haven't provided enough information to know what you're actually asking for.  You may need to edit your question and add some more details about exactly what you don't understand before anybody can provide a good answer.

Comment: I think it's a name, a period of time, so its function in the sentence is as a noun. But, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @BillJ Why shouldn't it be a noun? I thought grammatical functions are limited to "noun, pronoun, verb, adverb, adjective" and familiar functionalities like those which are familiar for a lower intermediate student like me. What do "head of NP" and "compliment of preposition" mean, after all?

Comment: All items in a clause are assigned two labels, a function label and a category (part of speech) label. It's vital that you do not muddle them up.The main functions are subject, object, complement, determiner, head, and marker. Categories (parts of speech) are noun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition etc. "The 1600s" is seen as a noun phrase by the presence of the determiner "the" and the plural "s". Preps like "of" require a complement like a noun to complete their meaning, so "of the 1600s" is a preposition phrase with "of" as **head** word, and the NP "the 1600s" as its **complement**.

Answer (score -1):

1600's may refer to: The period from 1600 to 1699, synonymous with the 17th century. The period from 1600 to 1609, known as the 1600s decade.